# How do I specify one type argument and let Rust infer the rest?

Tags: rust, typing, inference

I'm in the following situation:

```rust
fn some_fn<K, T, F, S>(func: F, other_func: S) -> Vec<i64>
where
    K: SomeType<T>,
    T: SomeOtherType,
    F: Fn() -> (),
    S: Fn() -> (),
{
    //...
}
```

For the above example, Rust can correctly infer types `T`, `F`, and `S`, but not `K` (as is expected).

Is there a way to only specify the type of `K` when calling `some_fn` without also specifying `T`, `F`, and `S`?

My current workaround is to change the signature to `some_fn` to `fn some_fn<K, T, F, S>(cheat: Option<K>, func: F, other_func: S)` and call the function like so:

```rust
let cheat: Option<SomethingThatImplements> = None;
let result = some_fn(cheat, func, other_func);
```

However, I find this to be very clunky. I haven't been able to find anything regarding this topic, is it even possible to specify only part of the type args?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Use `_` for the arguments you want to infer:

```rust
some_fn::<Foo, _, _, _>(...);
```